# Rolling upgrade machines using Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am going to use Chef to do rolling upgrade my Chef enabled VMs.
What I want is:

1. Do some changes on one VM, say update OS configuration
2. Restart the VM or just restart a service (like Windows Service)
3. Wait until the VM (or windows service) back to normal
4. Start upgrading next VM

How can Chef support such scenario? Any example I can learn from?

Answer (score 2):

Chef itself only groks the "change one machine" part of that for the most part. If you're already running chef-client as a daemon on a relatively short interval some people have used the Consul or ZK APIs from recipe code to implement a rolling gate/block system. Another option is to use some kind of central orchestration, personally I prefer Fabric but RunDeck, Chef Push Jobs, and MCollective are all options.

Comment: To complement on the 'gate' systems there's two cookbooks I know of for this [chef-dominodes](https://github.com/websterclay/chef-dominodes) (very old and using databags, so need to manage ACL and so on) and one using dynamodb locks named [rolling_restart](https://github.com/custora/rolling_restart). IMHO an external orchestration tool is better suited.